# Use of an if statement with open workbook variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to simplify some code, and wondered whether I would be able to use an If statement to set a different open workbook variable, depending on a few conditions of a defined range.

basically something like

```
dim ws as worksheet: set ws = Thisworkbook.worksheet("worksheet name")
dim r as range: set range = ws.range("A cell which has an if statement in it to display a number based on another cells contents")
dim wb as workbook
```

this is where I want to vary the actual workbook set as wb

```
if r.value = 1 then
set wb = Open a workbook
elseif r.value = 2 then
set wb = Open another workbook
```

Ideally I would then do the same for ws2 which would be the specific worksheet variable for the specified workbook above

Not sure if this method will work and wondered if I was on the right track.  I have code which opens a workbook, finds values in various rows, inserts rows, copies cell contents., between two ws variables, etc.  And it works, but I need ot add more workbook options and Id rather not have multiple macros with the only difference being the variable for the second workbook to open and work with.

Answer (score 0):

Its OK - tried the above and it seems to work fine - just lacked a bit of confidence I suppose.